# Record all Java input

Tags: java, input, bytecode

I´m going to write an application to modify java bytecode in order to record all the input (files, network, user input) in the execution.
In order to do this, I only need to wrap the java.io native methods? Is there any other source of input ?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Check AspectJ. It provides higher level API to what you are going to do.

Other possibility is using conventional tools. For example sockets are created via SocketFactory that can be substituted by calling special static method. So you can substitute real socket by yours own and get access to each byte passed through the socket. Although I implemented a prototype of such system about 6-7 year ago I do not remember by heart all details. I believe you can investigate them yourself. But AspectJ approach is easier (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I used AspectJ not so long ago, but since its oriented to aspects, I still have to know what are all the sources of input in order to define them as join points. That is my main question.